# unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, local-storage

### About

I am trying to save items in `LocalStorage` by:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let input = document.getElementById('task').value;
    let tasks;
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
        tasks = [];
    } else {
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }
    tasks.push(input);
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
})
```

### Issue

This doesn't seem to be saving my values, and I get the error:

```
Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `console.log()`, the value of `localStorage.getItem('tasks')` to see what it holds. It sounds like it's holding a value which isn't valid JSON, and so it cannot be parsed. You'll need to remove it from local storage to get your code to run

Comment: Thank You Brother Previously i used storage tasks that was still stored in localStrorage, and also using it again with out clearing it, for that purpose i got that error, thank You

Comment: `Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse` Indicates that the json you are trying to parse is not a valid json, could you share the value of tasks in localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your localStorage and running your code again. If you had a previous value saved in there that was not a valid JSON-parsable object, it would never be over-ridden since your code would fail before that.

If that does not work, try replacing `localStorage` with `window.localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following:

```
var myjson = localStorage.getItem('tasks');
console.log(myjson);
if (myjson === null ) {
    tasks = [];
} else{
    tasks = JSON.parse(myjson);
}
```

Confirm myjson is a valid json object.

You can use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json object.

Answer (score 0):

This might a problem in setting the local storage as well. Please make sure that the value that you are trying to set in the local storage is being saved.

If the above is true then you can proceed with something like the below code:

```
var objJson = localStorage.getItem('tasks');

objTasks = objJson ? JSON.parse(objJson) : [];
```

The above lines of code is going to make sure that the value for the local storage "tasks" is retrieved and if its retrieved and the value isn't null and not empty then and then only it will get parsed.